# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning even when there is a .catch on promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

i have the following problem that i can not figure out. here is my code:

```
//file1.js
module.exports = {
delete: function(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

      setTimeout(() => {reject('bla bla');}, 2000);

       });
  }
}


//file2.js 

const file1 = require('file1');
var delPr = file1.delete(id);

    delPr.then(() => {
      console.log('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++');
      res.status(200).json({
        message : "delete post"
      });});

    delPr.catch((error) => {

      console.log('-----------------------------');
}
```

when this is the code i get:

```
-----------------------------
(node:102437) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: bla bla
(node:102437) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:102437) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

when changing my code in file2.js to :

```
file1.delete(id).then(() => {
  console.log('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++');
  res.status(200).json({
    message : "delete post"
  });}).catch((error) => {

  console.log('-----------------------------');
  });
});
```

everything works fine and i only get the '--------' in the console, can someone please explain what is the difference?? i don't see one, and iv'e been on it for the past 3 hours.

Comment: The return value of `delPr.then(…)` is not the same as `delPr`

Comment: can you elaborate ??? you say that the `then` clause getting hit , so why i don't see the the `++++` print ???

Comment: I don't say that the fulfillment callback gets called. I say that the `.then()` method invocation itself returns something other than `delPr`, that's the difference that you didn't see

Comment: the `.then()` invoked only on fulfillment , or i'm wrong?

Comment: The first *callback* is only invoked on fulfillment. The promise `then` method is always invoked when you are creating the chain.

Comment: so the `.catch()` also get invoked when creating the  chain?

Comment: Yes. And they both return new promises, not the `delPr`. So when you chain them it works differently than when you invoke both on `delPr`.

Comment: so how i suppose to know which promise get resolve/reject ? the `delPr` the one from the `then` or the one from `catch`??

Comment: All of them, at some time. You might want to read the docs about in which cases the promises returned by `then`/`catch` get fulfiled/rejected.

Comment: will do - thanks a lot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180811/discussion-between-ddor254-and-bergi).

Answer (score 1):

yes `.then()` returns a promise and that promise is not handled.

so when you do `a.then().catch()` then rejection on that promise is handled by the catch

Comment: I don't understand , isn't the `reject` work on the original promise ?? The `delPr`?? How the promise can be resolved and enter the `then` clouse and also be catched with `catch`?